# Создание объекта класса, полем которого является список объектов другого класса

Tags: python, django

В модели Django создаю класс, допустим Продукты

```
class ProductClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50, default='')
    package_price = models.FloatField()
    package_amount = models.FloatField()
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(SupplierClass)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Теперь мы из продуктов делаем какое-то изделие

```
class DishClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50, default='')
    price = models.FloatField()
    products = models.***???***
```

И вот тут случился затык... Поле продуктов в объекте класса DishClass это набор объектов класса ProductClass, при этом кол-во объектов может быть произвольным, как один так и тысяча.

Потому имею два вопроса

1. Как правильно объявить поле products класса DishClass? И как правильно создавать объекты класса DishClass?
2. Можно ли как-то дефолту полю price класса ProductClass задавать значение равное делению других полей, конкретно package_price / package_amount ? Или это нужно делать только в момент создания объекта класса?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Кажется я как-то глубоко начал копать и усложнять задачу... Это просто many-to-many
Соответственно ответ на мой вопрос

      products =  models.ManyToManyField(ProductClass)

Пошел пробовать. Если все заработает напишу UPD